# Show that $(m-1)^{n-1}*n^{m-2}=\binom{n+m-1}{n}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I need help proving that $(m-1)^{n-1}*n^{m-2}=\binom{n+m-1}{n}$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.Stackexchange!  In order to help us help you, could you edit your post to give us your thoughts on the problem: what you know, what you've tried, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false.  Let $m=2$ and $n=2$.  Then $$(2-1)^{2-1}\cdot2^{2-2}=1\neq3={2+2-1\choose2}$$

Comment: whoops I must have read the data wrong. Thanks